# sql server data file location Permission

Tags: sql-server

I have a vps and on it I install sql server express and host some sites.
in same hard drive I locate web site content and Databases datafile.
I chnage the permission of the root of drive and only Administrator and sytem have permission to read or write.

web sites work perfectly but I can't create any database on this drive.from SQL server management this drive dosnt show and I can't select folder on it for datafile location.

Which permission are needed by sql server to find a path and write file on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what service login account SQL Server is using. If you installed it as a domain user, that would explain the problems you're having. In that case you can either:

- add that user to the ACL for the drive, or
- change SQL Server's service login account to an account you've got in the ACL.

Comment: I add Serive account to ACL and it works